# How to change the format of date during fetching from Db in YII?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using rest api calla in yii.

this is my model

```
class  User extends ActiveRecord
    {

    }
```

IN controller, I have getting data from db by following code

```
$person = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(['*'])
                ->from('person')
                ->all();
```

One date field is there in person table (ex:createdTime).

Now I'm getting date format. Here I want to change in long. Where can I change/set the model for this object

Comment: Why you are getting models like that if you have `User` model?

Comment: No. It is seprate model. I configured new one here.

Comment: Why you are using `yii\db\Query` instead of `YourModel::find()`?

Comment: My question is need to change date to milliseconds when fetching from db. Where have to change?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use model for that, you can change it in simple loop:

```
$results = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['*']) // you can omit this, it's redundant
    ->from('person')
    ->all();

foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
    $results[$key]['created_at'] = ... // replace with new value;
}
```

But I highly recommend use model instead, then you can use built-in [ArrayHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-arrayhelper.html) [toArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#toArray%28%29-detail) method to process attribute values or even add new attributes / modify their names. Example:

```
use app\models\User;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

...

$initialModels = User::find()->all();
$models = ArrayHelper::toArray($models, [
    'app\models\User' => [
        'created_at' => function ($model) {
            return ...; // Return new value here
        },
    ],
]);
```

More info is available in official docs.

Comment: I also covered this in answer.

Comment: Is it correct?  $person[$key]['dob'] = strtotime(date($person[$key]['dob']));

Comment: Depends on your needs and choosed option. In the right part use `$person['dob']` instead.

Comment: No im asking about  strtotime(date($person[$key]['dob']))